# Entity Framework: Extending partial class with interface without touching the EF-generated classes

Tags: c#, interface, entity-framework-5, partial-classes

My problem is similar to this post:
[Interface inheritance in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093897/interface-inheritance-in-entity-framework?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Thus, I copy that example and modify it for my issue:

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

// The following two classes are generated by Entity Framework
public partial class SomeEntity
{
    public int SomeEntityId { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public partial class OtherEntity
{
    public int OtherEntityId { get; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is the following:

```
public partial class SomeEntity : IBaseEntity
    {
        // No code needed here because the other partial class
        // already has the needed properties
    }
```

But then I get the following errors:

```
Error 64 '[...].SomeEntity' does not implement interface member '[...]IBaseEntity.CreatedOn'
Error 64 '[...].SomeEntity' does not implement interface member '[...]IBaseEntity.CreatedBy'
```

Obviously I can see that, too. 
But I thought that after compiling, the partial classes will become one, so that the compiler should not complain.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do theses classes in the same namespace?

Comment: Actually, that was the sticking point. I just changed the namespace path of the secondly mentioned partial class to the generated partial class and the compiler doesn't complain anymore now.

Comment: So it was just a namespace issue, because I had a very similar situation and it worked just fine because my partials were in the same namespace as my EF generated objects. I had an interface and just implemented the interface on the partial classes and it worked just fine.

Comment: Holy mole. Can't believe that was the problem, just encountered this myself. Pls set an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, and i resolved moving partial class outside App_Code folder!
I should admit that i don't understand the reason :-(

Comment: This is a meaningless answer. We don't know your App_Code folder and moving classes doesn't necessarily change their namespaces (and that was the issue).

Comment: You don't understand. It is a web site and you should now what app_code folder is. If you don't now, please do not write nothing

Comment: I know what app_code is. I don't know your app_code. Moreover, we don't even know if OP's code is anywhere near an app_code folder.