# Make an entity generated by Entity Framework implement an interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I have this interface:

```
public interface X {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
}
```

And I want an entity generated by Entity Framework that have this properties to implement this interface.
How I do it?
I tried to do a partial class but I get a compile error that force me to implement the properties in interface as I show below.

```
public partial class A : X {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class generated by Entity Framework:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace App
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class A
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public A()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have these current files:

1.

```
namespace ConfApp.model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class INSTITUICAO
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public INSTITUICAO()
        {
            this.UTILIZADOR = new HashSet<UTILIZADOR>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Morada { get; set; }
        public string Pais { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UTILIZADOR> UTILIZADOR { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.

```
namespace ConfApp.model {
    public interface IInstituicao {
        int Id { get; set; }
        String Nome { get; set; }
        String Morada { get; set; }
        String Pais { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3.

```
namespace ConfApp.model {
    public partial class INSTITUICAO: IInstituicao {
    }
}
```

Comment: try with BaseClass, Inherit your Entity class from base Class.

Comment: Can you share the compile error?

Comment: @Simonare You are saying I should do that in the file generated by the Entity Framework?

Comment: @pfx The compiler error says that I should implement the properties

Comment: I don't think this is really what you want to do... If it's database first then how would you expect to add properties / columns at run time???

I expect more on course would be generic methods? `<TEntity> GetId(this Entity entity){}` maybe?

Comment: Can you show the class generated by Entity Framework?

Comment: according to OP's edit? why are you trying to implement an interface for this class?

Comment: @pfx The post was edited with that class

Comment: @Simonare I want to implement this interface because that way I can have different DAL's and don't need the modify the UI of my App

Comment: can you show us with sample code what you are trying to achieve if you can eliminate this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you have both partial classes in the same namespace? Can you show the complete declaration of each including namespace. I assume they are in the same assembly also, right?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057349/entity-framework-extending-partial-class-with-interface-without-touching-the-ef which was a namespace issue.

Comment: @IanMercer No, I don't have in the same namespace

Comment: you should have it in same namespace, otherwise it won't work and you got error

Comment: @IanMercer I changed to the same namespace and have the same problem

Comment: you need to inherit INSTITUICAO class.   `INSTITUICAO : IInstituicao`

Comment: Yes i fixed that and have the same problem

Comment: If I paste (1)-(3) into a .CS file, add the missing class, it compiles just fine. Are you sure you writing these in the same Assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class generated by Entity Framework already contains the properties for the interface, you only have to declare the interface upon class `A`.

The whole picture might include the following 3 files.
**Make sure that the names and namespaces of these partial classes match and that both `.cs` files are part of the same Visual Studio project.**

1. The interface `X.cs`
   *(By convention, prefix an interface by `I` as in `IX`.)*

   ```
   namespace App
   {
       public interface X {
           int Id { get; set; }
           int Number { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The class generated by Entity Framework `A.cs`
   *(Leave this auto-generated one as-is, which will look like below.)*

   ```
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // <auto-generated>
   //     This code was generated from a template.
   //
   //     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
   //     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
   // </auto-generated>
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   namespace App
   {
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;

       public partial class A
       {
           [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
           public A()
           {
           }

           public int Id { get; set; }
           public int Number { get; set; }
       }
   }
   ```
3. The declaration of the interface `X` on class `A` in eg. `A.partial.cs`

   ```
   namespace App
   {
       public partial class A : X {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: In point 2 I can't implement interface in the class generated because it has this command

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: That was I typo on my side; fixed it.

Comment: Yes I have that code but got that compile error I was talking about

Comment: So you have 3 separate files with the content as above? Try to store file 3 in separate folder, different from the one Entity Framework is using.

Comment: Yes I have that

Comment: Can you update your question with the code as in these 3 files? _(This is compiling at my side :/)_

Comment: The names of your partial classes don't match `EFInstituicao` vs `INSTITUICAO`.

Comment: Are all conditions in my comment in bold fullfilled?

Comment: I fixed that and have same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IBaseEntity {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose that you have StudentEntity.cs generated by Entity Framework

```
namespace MyProject.DAL.Entities
{
    public partial class StudentEntity
    { }
}
```

create new file StudentEntityExtended.cs and inside that put your partial class

```
namespace MyProject.DAL.Entities
{
    public partial class StudentEntity : IBaseEntity {

    }
}
```

then

```
public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolContext(): base()
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Now Students DbSet is inheriting from BaseClass thus having properties from its anchestory

Comment: You can't do that because what he's trying to do is adding the implementation of an interface to the partial class generated by Entity Framework

Comment: we actually need to ask why he cannot do that? does he have another BaseClass implementation? then why he is not using that? I believe that something is wrong here

Comment: I cannot do that because the class generated by EF have a comment saying I should not modify the code like I show above in the edit

Comment: You can have another partial class and you can inherit it there. That is why we are using partial classes.

Comment: I converted it to interface, now it makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, It needs to implement IBaseEntity

Comment: Yes I actually have that but I get a compile error saying i should implement the properties

Comment: then one of your property or both have different signature. Id and Number is generated by EF Right?

Comment: Yes they have the same signature and EF have the properties

Comment: there is no other option. you are missing something. a tiny bit. look closer :)

Comment: you need to inherit INSTITUICAO class.   `INSTITUICAO : IInstituicao`